# How to pass document id dynamically in help url?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I tried to pass document id dynamically and i am going to render that pdf document when we click on help link. but not getting how to achieve this..

here in below pageblock component i want to pass the id dynamically in help url,

```
   <apex:pageBlock id="menoPageBlockBtn" helpTitle="Help" helpUrl="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015L00000008icY" rendered="{!isComplete}" tabStyle="Account">
```

in class it seems i need to add this,

```
    public string documentid {get;set;}

    Document d = [Select d.Id From Document d where d.DeveloperName = 'check_form'];
    documentid = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+d.Id;
```

Please tell me how do i achieve this?

Comment: What do you have in your class so far john?

Comment: i have added this in class, public string documentid(){
     Document d = [Select d.Id From Document d where d.DeveloperName = 'Complete_On_Study_Eligibility_form'];
     documentid = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+d.Id;
     system.debug('documentid :'+documentid);
     return documentid;
    }

Answer (score 1):

In Controller use this code:

```
public Document doc{get;set;}
```

Inside constructor:

```
doc =new Document();
doc =[Select d.Id From Document d where d.DeveloperName = 'check_form' limit 1];
```

In Visualforce page use this code

```
<apex:pageBlock id="menoPageBlockBtn" helpTitle="Help" helpUrl="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!doc.id}" rendered="{!isComplete}" tabStyle="Account">
```

Answer (score 0):

vf page:

```
   <apex:pageBlock id="menoPageBlockBtn" helpTitle="Help"  helpUrl="{!documentid}" rendered="     {!isComplete}" tabStyle="Account">
```

class:

```
 public string documentid {
    get{
        Document d = [Select d.Id From Document d where d.DeveloperName = 'check_form'];
        documentid = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+d.Id;
        system.debug('documentid :'+documentid);
        return documentid;  
    }
    set;
}
```

It has done right now...thanks any ways to all....